# Regex to find numerical data from a group of JSON

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to build a regex to find the numerical data in the series of a output which combines many small JSON data. This is just like to find the numerical data after `:` but I am not able to get through it I tried many regex and used the hint from many websites but am not able to solve it.

The data is somewhat like

```
{"orders":[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":5},{"id":6},{"id":7},{"id":8},{"id":9},{"id":10},{"id":11},{"i
d":648},{"id":649},{"id":650},{"id":651},{"id":652},{"id":653}],"errors":[{"code":3,"message":"[PHP
Warning #2] count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable
(153)"}]}
```

Here I want all the numerical values except `#2`and `(153)`.

Please Help

Comment: Try using https://regex101.com/ to figure out the regex for you. Also another way you can do is load json to your program and use loops to filter the data.

Comment: Are you showing us a JSON string? Why not deserialize to python? Then the "numerical data after :" is a python dict with key "id".

Comment: Yes, This works. I didn't thought of that. Thank You @tdelaney

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
(?<=:)\d+
```

Maybe negative lookbehind works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org) for this:

Install pandas like:

```
pip install pandas
```

Now, use [`pd.json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html) to read the `json` into a `dataframe`:

```
In [248]: import pandas as pd

In [241]: j = {"orders":[{"id":1},{"id":2},{"id":3},{"id":4},{"id":5},{"id":6},{"id":7},{"id":8},{"id":9},{"id":10},{"id":11},{"id":648},{"id":649},{"id":650},{"id":651},{"id":652},{"id":653}],"errors":[{"code":3,"message":"[PHP Warning #2] count(): Para
     ...: meter must be an array or an object that implements Countable(153)"}]}

In [249]: l = pd.json_normalize(j['orders'])['id'].tolist()

In [250]: l
Out[250]: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 648, 649, 650, 651, 652, 653]
```

Comment: Thanks for the effort brother! But I also want the  integer value that is 
{"code":3,
​

Answer (score 0):

Save your json in a variable. Here i stored in test
Then use below list comprehension to get the values

```
[i["id"] for i in test["orders"]]

[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 648, 649, 650, 651, 652, 653]
```

If you need all integers in entire string(json as string)
save your json in string. Here i stored in test

```
[i for i in re.findall(":(\d*)",test) if i]
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '648', '649', '650', '651', '652', '653', '3']
```